# What is the different functionality of the CA certificates in Kubernetes?

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, certificate-authority

I am new to kubernetes. here I have some confusions about the CA certificates used in a kubernetes cluster. As far as I know there are several CA certificates in kubernetes, but still not clear what each  functionality of them. Here is my understanding of them, but still not sure of them.

1. Root CA also know as  serving CA,

   - it signs the apiserver certwhich are configured in the apiserver with --tls-cert-file and --tls-private-key-file.
   - this CA certificate is configured in kube-controller-manager with --root-ca-file
2. Client CA

   - this CA certificate can be a intermediate CA certificate signed by ROOT CA certificate.
   - which is used to sign the individual components in cluster, help to identify their identities when RBAC and NODE authorization are enabled. for example, sign the kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, kube-proxy, kubelet.
   - can be configured in apiserver with --client-ca-file
3. requestheader client ca

   - this CA certificate can also be a intermediate CA certificate signed by ROOT CA certificate.
   - Still not understand what this CA is used for ? what scenario of the CA file, just found that if metric server is deployed, it will ask for  requestheader related certificates and keys
   - for --proxy-client-cert-file and  --proxy-client-key-file in kube-apiserver, what the value of these parameter? can kubelet certificates and keys be used?

Besides these CA certificates, some other certificates relative confusions are also encountered.

1. --service-account-key-file parameter in kube-apiserver and kube-controller-manager, which file can be configured? is the apiserver key file or ROOT CA key file ?
2. what can be set to
   --cluster-signing-cert-file and --cluster-signing-key-file  in kube-controller-manager? can we use client ca and client ca key file?

Answer (score 3):

A good summary is at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54665#issuecomment-340960398

The request header CA is used to verify a client cert presented by an authenticating proxy along with user info set in request headers. The proxy authenticated the user, proxies the request, and sets username/groups in headers. The API server verifies the client cert before trusting user info in any headers.